# Displace modifier does not match the texture

Tags: displacement

I'm having troubles since few hours to texture a mesh (a character's face) : it has a texture made from different maps (color, AO, normal..) made from Nodes.
[image]

I finally want to use a displacement map to physically slice or displace the mesh through a given image, so I use a Multires + a Displace modifier.

The displace modifier is set to follow the UV Map on which my mesh is unwrapped.
[image]

But in the end, **the displacement does not fit with the other components of the texture (especially the color & normal map)**. It is **not scaled the same, neither mapped the same**.

I saw some posts giving the crop settings of the displace modifier as a solution, but it is not practical at all.

Do you have any solution ? :(
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok everything you saw in my first post was properly set, except that **my unwrapping was wrong : some parts of the mesh (a complex one btw) were crossing each other on the UV map, causing the wrong displacement mapping**.

That was pretty obvious in the end.

I deliberately chose to cross some parts of it because I wanted a specific texture mapping. **So, for any person interested in this post, I guess that it would be possible to correctly map the displacement with some crossing unwrapped parts of the mesh by using multiple UV map**.